# Vertx is not binding Routers

Tags: java, microservices, vert.x

Well, i felt myself really lost with Vertx structure due to everything is a lambda expression. 
i followed [this](https://www.devcon5.ch/en/blog/2017/09/15/vertx-modular-router-design/) tutorial exactly in order to well structure my application,
unfortunately it doesn't register any router i have no idea why. pleasefind bellow what i did

serviceEndPoint same with the above tutorial

```
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;

public interface ServiceEndPoint {
    String mountPoint();

    Router router(Vertx vertx);
}
```

and here is the subscriptionService

```
import com.poc.poc.repositories.SubscriptionRepository;
import com.poc.poc.services.ServiceEndPoint;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;

public class SubscriptionService implements ServiceEndPoint {
    private SubscriptionRepository subscriptionRepository;

    public SubscriptionService() {
        subscriptionRepository = new SubscriptionRepository();

    }

    @Override
    public String mountPoint() {
        return "/test";
    }

    @Override
    public Router router(Vertx vertx) {
        Router router = Router.router(vertx);
        router.get("/test").handler(rc -> rc.response().end(subscriptionRepository.getSubscriptionInfo(rc, vertx).toString()));
        return router;
    }
}
```

And finally here is the server vertical

```
import com.poc.poc.services.ServiceEndPoint;
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Future;

import java.util.ServiceLoader;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;

public class ServerVertical extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start(final Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {

        ServiceLoader<ServiceEndPoint> loader = ServiceLoader.load(ServiceEndPoint.class);

        Router main = StreamSupport.stream(loader.spliterator(), false)
            .collect(() -> Router.router(vertx), //the main router
                (r, s) -> r.mountSubRouter(s.mountPoint(), s.router(vertx)),
                (r1, r2) -> {
                });

        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(main::accept).listen(8080, res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                startFuture.complete();
            } else {
                startFuture.fail(res.cause());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Please be noted once i run the application, im getting those warnings

```
Jun 12, 2018 6:16:45 PM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,main] has been blocked for 2486 ms, time limit is 2000
Jun 12, 2018 6:16:46 PM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,main] has been blocked for 3485 ms, time limit is 2000
```

by the way  `Router main = StreamSupport.stream(loader.spliterator(), false)` size is 0.

any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, not everything in Vert.x is a lambda expression. That's just quite a weird tutorial you've found. As you can see, it uses `java.util.ServiceLoader` which is not a Vert.x class. Nor I'm familiar with anyone else recommending to use this class with Vert.x applications.
What it tries to do is to load your classes dynamically. What you probably miss is putting the correct file in `META-INF` directory, as described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html#register-service-providers

Anyway, that's not the way I would recommend to use VertX. Instead, go with the regular VertX tutorial, which is excellent: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_handling_requests_and_calling_the_next_handler

Comment: interesting, can i make a middleware also ? i mean i want to add some attribute to each request that i get

Comment: I actually covered it in another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46015735/5985853 The gist is that you call `ctx.next()` in your "middleware" route, and it will continue the chain.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created you *service interface* (`com.poc.poc.services.ServiceEndPoint`) declaration and the concrete implementation (`SubscriptionService`), you should add the **service provider binding**.

As per the `ServiceLocator` documentation, the binding should be inserted under a file named after you interface FQN, i.e. under ***META-INF/services/com.poc.poc.services.ServiceEndPoint*** (The whole directory structure goes under the project / module *resources* directory).

The file will contain the actual interface implementation:

```
com.poc.poc.services.SubscriptionService
```